# Input Data does not save immediately only after exiting program

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am making a business tracking app where a user can type in a product's name with price and that data is turned into a dictionary and is saved in a Database (a txt  file.)

Then the key and value pair is loaded into a Label's text so the user can see all of their products.

I've added an 'add new product' mechanic to the program (which just saves input data from the user in the database) and it works just fine, but the problem is that after the new product is saved it does not appear on the Label's text but when I exit out of the program and run it, then new products appear.

So I experimented little with the program, I created a new label where all the products amount number is showed when a button is clicked, it shows a number (amount of product stored number*) and it is also printed to the console. It showed all the products stored before the program opened but didnt show the new ones entered by the user.

Lastly i checked the txt file after the user saves newly added products and after the program is closed, then the new products show in the text file.

So how do I save new products immediately after user saved them?

py:

```
...
class Screen_two(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_amount_label, 5)

    def update_amount_label_with_textinput(self, dt):
        self.ids.productsamount.text = 'From Textinput: {}'.format(db.databaseDict)

    def update_amount_label(self, dt):
        n = 0
        for i in db.databaseDict.items():
            n += 1
        self.ids.productsamount.text = 'Amount of goods: {}'.format(n)
        print(n)

    def addbtn(self):
        open_addbut_popup()

    def edbtn(self):
        open_edbut_popup()

    def delbtn(self):
        open_delbut_popup()
...
class GoodsView(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.post_init, 0)



    def post_init(self, dt):        
            
                                    #here it is where new labels are generated

        n = 0
        for k, v in db.databaseDict.items():
            n += 1
            self.LBL1 = NicerLabel(
                text=str(k),
                size_hint=(1.5, 1),
                font_size='15sp',
                halign='right')

            self.LBL3 = NicerLabel(
                text=':',
                font_size='18sp',
                size_hint=(.075, 1))

            self.LBL2 = NicerLabel(
                text=str(v),
                font_size='15sp',
                size_hint=(.3, 1))


            self.ids.GoodsContainer.add_widget(self.LBL1)
            self.ids.GoodsContainer.add_widget(self.LBL3)
            self.ids.GoodsContainer.add_widget(self.LBL2)
...
class addbut_popup(FloatLayout):
    addprodname = ObjectProperty(None)
    addprodprice = ObjectProperty(None)

             #here the new products are sent to database and saved being there 


    def add_product(self):
        if self.addprodname.text != "" and '.' not in self.addprodname.text:
            if re.findall(r'\D', self.addprodprice.text) == []:
                db.add_product(self.addprodname.text, self.addprodprice.text)

                self.reset()
            else:
                invalid()
                self.reset()
        else:
            invalid()
            self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.addprodname.text = ''
        self.addprodprice.text = ''
...
```

Database.py:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, CalculatorDatabase):
        self.CalculatorDatabase = CalculatorDatabase
        self.database = None
        self.databaseDict = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.database = open(self.CalculatorDatabase, 'r')
        self.databaseDict = {}
        for line in self.database:
            name, price = line.split(':')
            self.databaseDict[name] = price
        self.database.close()

    def add_product(self, product_name, product_price):
        with open(self.CalculatorDatabase, 'a') as text:
            text.write('{}: {}\n'.format(product_name, product_price))
```

kv:

```
...
         # this is the part where i experimented with label text and textinput 
         # so i could understand my problem better 

<Screen_two>:                 
    productsamount:productsamount
    textinput:textinput
    Label:
        text: 'amount'
        font_size:'11dp'
        id:productsamount
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size_hint: .15, .05
        pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .95}
    Button:
        text:'change_amount'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size_hint: .15, .05
        pos_hint: {'x': .4, 'y': .95}
        on_release:
            root.update_amount_label_with_textinput(None)
    TextInput:
        id:textinput
        text:'enter:'

        size_hint: .15, .05
        pos_hint: {'x': .7, 'y': .95}

...

<addbut_popup>:
    addprodname:addprodname
    addprodprice:addprodprice
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: .7, .2
        pos_hint: {'x': .15,'y': .75}
        spacing:5
        cols:2
        rows:2
        Label:
            text: 'Aru nev:'
            size_hint: .35, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
        TextInput:
            id:addprodname
            multiline:False
        Label:
            text: 'Aru ar:'
            size_hint: .35, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
        TextInput:
            id:addprodprice
            multiline:False
    Button:
        text: 'ADD'
        size_hint: .3, .2
        pos_hint: {'x': .35,'y': .35}
        on_release: root.add_product()
...
```

Comment: It looks like you are writing the new product to your database file, but that is not sufficient to get the new product displayed anywhere. You would need to either re-read the updated database file and re-create the product labels, or enter the new product into your `databaseDict` and add a new label for the new product.

Comment: very helpful comment thank you!